# Input redirection using dup2()

Tags: c++, io-redirection, execvp, dup2

So I am trying to implement the following command line statement in c++ by using dup2() and execvp(): `wc < inputFile.txt` then return to my command line. So basically I am forking a process and executing that command in the child process.
However my code the following error: `wc: stdin: read: Bad file descriptor`

Here is my code:

```
int file_desc = open(fileName.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_APPEND); 
int stdin = dup(0);
dup2(file_desc,0); 
execvp (args2[0], args2); // now execute
dup2(stdin, 0);
```

So my thought process was that I needed to redirect the standard in (aka index 0 of the file descriptor table) to the file descriptor of the file since at index is always stdin and that's where input is read from. Then after I execute, I replace it back with the original standard in. So I am confused about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your actual code does examine/test the return value of every function it calls, right?  Because if not, then any of them could be returning an error code and you wouldn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

The file_desc is opened only for writing (O_WRONLY) - try opening it for reading (O_RDONLY).

You might also want to:

- dup2() between fork() and exec() instead of saving and restoring stdin - less system calls and saves a race in multi-threaded apps.
- close file_desc in the parent process
- close file_desc in the child process after the dup2 (and before the exec)